# Url for microservices deployed in a docker swarm for REST communication

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have 3 microservices. They communicate with each other using REST calls through URLs which are provided in the application.yml files of each of the services. In normal deployment we just provide the IP address of the machine which has the microservice and the port.

How do we configure the url in docker in the yml file? Do we just provide the name of the service provided in the docker-compose file and the exposed port?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-swarm, every service name is by default resolvable. So you can access your service by its name instead of an IP. Alternatively, if you want to have another resolvable name for your service you can read here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases